# How to add a new variable in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, frontend

Hello everyone.

```
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#id_name_task").change(function () {
                var name_task = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    async: true,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    url: '{% url "validate_data" %}',
                    data: {
                        'name_task': name_task,
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        if (data.is_taken) {
                            alert("A task with this name already exists.");
                        }

                    },
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

It code - It checks the field and if there is such data in the database, shows the window- alert.
I want to check another field.

```
    <p><label for="id_category_task">Category task:</label> <select
            name="category_task" required="" id="id_category_task">
        <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

        <option value="1">One</option>

        <option value="2">Two</option>

        <option value="3">Three</option>

    </select></p>
```

For example, the user clicks on "One" and I want to will get the data.
But I do not understand how to add two variables in jquery code. And how to find need data.
[image]

It no show me my choice text. I need new `$(document).ready(function ()` , right? Or not?
I hope you will help me.
Thank you.

Comment: Inside `data: {
                        'name_task': name_task,
                    },` you can send as many variables as you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have multiple `select` elements:

```
<select id="id_name_task" class="combo">...</select>
<select id="id_category_task" class="combo">...</select>
```

You can register an event listener to `.combo` class and execute the appropriate action:

```
$(document).on('change', '.combo', function(e) {
    callAjax($(e.currentTarget);)
});

function callAjax(sender) {
    var senderId = sender.attr('id');
    var val = sender.val();
    $.ajax(function() {
        method: 'POST',
        url: '...',
        data: { senderId: senderId, val: val },
        success: function(data) {
            // Handle data
        },
        error: function() {
            // Handle error
        }
    });
}
```

Now, on your server side code, you can check the `senderId` and `val` parameters and send the appropriate response back to the client.

Comment: But how it to do if I do not any class?

Comment: If you cannot edit the HTML, and you do not have any class, try to get the select elements by tag name: $(document).on('change', 'select', ..). But now, you register an event listener to any select element in the document.